# Quick linked-list implementation

Tags: algorithm, c, linked-list

I need a simple singly-linked list to help implement some memory management functionality. I just finished writing it up and would really like a code review since I haven't written this particular data structure in a long time.

```
struct pid_node {

  int PID;
  struct pid_node* next; 

};

 struct pid_node* pid_node_create(int PID) {
   struct pid_node* new;
   new = kmalloc(sizeof(struct pid_node));
   if (new == NULL) return NULL;
   new->PID = PID;
   new->next = NULL;
   return new; 
 }

 void add_pid_node(struct pid_node* head, struct pid_node* new) {
   struct pid_node* temp;
   temp = head;
   while(temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next; 
   temp->next = new; 
 }

 void remove_pid_node(struct pid_node* head, struct pid_node* dead) {
   struct pid_node* temp, other_part_of_list, delete_node;
   temp = head;
   while(temp->next != NULL) {
     if (temp->next == dead) {
       delete_node = temp->next;
       other_part_of_list = temp->next->next;
       temp->next = other_part_of_list;
       kfree(delete_node); //don't leak memory
       return; 
     }
     temp = temp->next; 
   }
   kprintf("Got to end of PID list, didn't remove 'dead'!\n");
 }

 //returns true or false (1 or 0) if a particular PID is within my list
 int query_pid(int PID, struct pid_node* head) {
   struct pid_node* temp;
   temp = head;
   while(temp->next != NULL) {
     if (temp->PID == PID) return 1;
     temp = temp->next;
   }
   return 0; //didn't find it
  }
```

It doesn't have to be super fancy or anything. It just has to properly carry out the four functions.

Comment: Since you're using kmalloc, why don't you use [klist](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)?

Comment: It is best to make the code compile before submitting it for review (other_part_of_list, delete_node should be pointers).

Comment: Oh shoot, I meant for them to be pid_node* variables by listing them like that (e.g. int x, y, z). Does that not work for pointers?

Comment: EDITED - added another snippet of code I'm pretty is wrong that I want to implement.

Comment: @YoungMoney See my edit.

Comment: Why not have the delete function return a pointer to `head`; if the head is deleted, return the new one: `if (head == dead) { newhead = head->next; kfree(head); return newhead; }` otherwise return the old head.  Caller has to remember to assign head.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of conceptual errors:

## Pass by value

You can remove the temporary copy of `head` in your functions. In C, all arguments are passed by value. This means you can operate directly on the `head` parameter exposed to your function without worrying about the argument in the calling code. Although both point to the same location, each is a different pointer variable with its own address.

## Pointer declarations

```
struct pid_node* temp, other_part_of_list, delete_node;
```

Remember that the `*` is not part of the type, but part of the declarator. A clearer way to write declarations involving pointers is to move the `*` directly in front of the identifier. This follows the C convention that "declaration mimics use." So, the line changes to

```
struct pid_node *temp, other_part_of_list, delete_node;
```

Now the error (and fix) is obvious. If there is no `*` before a variable, its a variable of the type instead of a pointer to the type.

```
struct pid_node *temp, *other_part_of_list, *delete_node;
```

## Edit: remove `head` special case

In order to modify the `head` argument itself, which is a pointer-to-struct, you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct or return the new `head`. For example (pointer-to-pointer-to-struct):

```
void remove_pid_node(struct pid_node **head, struct pid_node *dead) {
...
    if (*head == dead) {
         temp = *head;
         *head = temp->next; 
         kfree(temp);
         return; 
    }
```

Then you would call the code like this:

```
remove_pid_node(&head, head);
```

Note: don't forget to check for `NULL` arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. About the pass-by-value: I understand what you're saying. but there's nothing wrong with what I'm doing right?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by wrong. Technically you can add as many extra variables you want to any function, but it decreases readability.

Comment: Ah, I just mean functionality-wise. It should work, yes?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: OK, I want to make a small addition to my remove function: a case for if the entry I want to remove is the head. I've added the code to the OP.

Comment: Regarding operating directly on `head`, using a `temp` is quite ok.  The compiler will optimise this away anyway.  Note that if you use `head` directly, your code becomes untruthful; variable `head` will point in sequence to all the members of the list and only at the start truly points to what its name says it points to. This could be considered wrong. Calling it something other than `head` would cure this.  I have worked at places where they would code this function parameter `const struct pid_node * const head`, (extra const) which prevents such modification, but that is just silly.

Comment: Wish I could give you guys more upvotes, code review is great!

Comment: @William Morris I agree that the `head` parameter deserves a better name. The primary reason I took issue with `temp`: the reflex betrays a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @mteckert:  The head param has a perfectly good name.  It's the head of the list.  The temp local variable needs a better name, but the general principle "don't muck about with the passed in parameters just because you can" is a good one to follow.

Comment: @William:  No don't rename the parameter.  It documents for the caller what they should pass in.  If you rename it to reflect how it is being used inside the function (as an iterator), you are leaking implementation details.  What needs to happen is that `temp` needs to be more descriptively named, that is all.

Comment: @JeremyP: you are right of course. To be fair I wasn't really recommending renaming, it was just an observation. I suppose there might be cases where naming the parameter (eg) `list` would be valid; for example if it were useful to pass a pointer to an arbitrary position in the list, not just the head.

Answer (score 2):

General:

- Algorithm looks good.
- Functions normally start with the brace on column 0.
- Add a typedef so that you can refer to just `pid_node *`, not `struct
  pid_node *`, throughout (except in the struct declaration).

  typedef struct pid_node pid_node;
- I usually prefer to assign an initial value to variables where they are
  declared (but that is just a personal preference):

  ```
   pid_node* temp = head;
   ...
  ```
- variables are not normally capitalized (`PID`)

add_pid_node:

- what if head == NULL ?

remove_pid_node

- best to put each variable definition on its own line.
- `other_part_of_list` and `delete_node` should be pointers.
- what if head == NULL ?
- `other_part_of_list` is not necessary:

  `temp->next = temp->next->next;`

query_pid:

- other functions have `head` first in parameter list, but here not.  Inconsistent.
- what if head == NULL ?
- `head` and `temp` should be `const`

Comment: Wow that was great! I will definitely do some revisions based on your comments. Thanks a bunch. EDIT - I guess in my head I was implicitly thinking that I would only ever call these functions when I know head is not NULL, but that's definitely not reliable/good practice.